# Specflow feature file shows step as both undefined and having mulitiple definitions at the same time

Tags: specflow

I have a specflow feature file. It has numerous scenarios in it.

In the editor, each step shows as purple (not defined). Right clicking in the feature file and selecting "Generate Step Definitions" pops a dialog for defining the definition methods for each step. Each step is listed. Generating those step definitions generates code whose signatures are identical to what already exists.

However...

If I right click on a step in the feature file and say "Go to definition," It pops a message saying that there are multiple definitions found and takes me to the first one. There are definitely no other steps named the same anywhere in the project at all.

What could be some things which could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular instance, it was a scope decorator for my feature steps file:

```
[Scope(Tag = "@myTag", Feature ="myFeature")]
```

which I understand as being necessary since we are using inheritance to deal with a very complex testing framework and specflow has elsewhere been described as not respecting inheritance (just goes by the [Binding] decorator).